# Akka get type of a actor

Tags: java, akka

I have two classes **A**, **B** both extends [untypedActor](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/actor/UntypedActor.html) and i created another actor **C** to
watch these two actors by using **getContext().watch(actorRef of A/b)**, when any of those those two actors A,B is terminated i am getting a Terminated message to C on which i have to restart it after some task depending on which actor terminated is either A or B.

How can i know which actor is terminated by any method like

```
 if(terminatedActor instanceOf A){
     // Do task on termination of A
     // create A
 }else if(terminatedActor instanceOf B ){
     // Do task on termination of B
     // create B
 }
```

Comment: In your case is it feasible to introduce another "layer of management" in between, so one middle mgr handles only As, the other only Bs?

Comment: yes, but what in case of more actors of different actors to be monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to monitor only 2-3 types of actor, so i implemented different monitor for each of these types.

Answer (score 2):

As the ActorRef is just a proxy to the implementation it doesn't give you the information you need.

The way I manage this is to store a reference to the actors I create in the supervisor which indicates the type. There are various ways you could do this, one approach I've used is to store the ActorRef's in a Map. You can then use the Terminated ActorRef to get the value from the Map that tells you what type it was. Alternatively just create internal properties on the UntypedActor to hold the refs then check one until you find a match and recreate it.

Comment: i already did that and trying to know whether akka provides any facility to do so

Comment: Ah right, not that I'm aware of. As far as I know this is the standard approach to achieve what you require.